# Combination or Permutation... or something else?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I have been having trouble with this problem, and I can't seem to find a definite answer on how to work it out.

Q. A rugby league team of 13 consists of five backs, six forwards and two
halves.
How many teams are possible from a squad of 17, consisting of six
backs, eight forwards and two halves, and one player who could play
as a back or a half?

Normally I would treat it as a combination, but I am unsure how to treat the last player which can play as either, because if he/she is chosen for one position, they are no longer there for selection for the second possible position. (So I can't double them up).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT

I would consider the following three possibilities:

1. The player that can double is picked as a back
2. The player that can double is picked as a half
3. The player that can double is not picked at all

Calculate the number of possibilities for each of those, and add them up.

Comment: Edit. Whoops I had the wrong problem up with my initial reply. so I would go 8C6 * ( (7C5 * 2C2) + (6C5 * 3C2) ?

Comment: @kitkat1224 You should have three cases, not two.  Also, you are selecting from six backs, not $7$.  If the player who can play both half and back is selected as a back, that means you need to pick four of the other six backs to fill the backfield with five backs.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, I just don't know how to express that mathematically. Would I have (6C4 * 2C2) + (6C5 * 2C1) + (6C5 * 2C2) ??

Comment: @kitkat1224 All cases: 8C6 for the forwards. Case 1: 6C4 for the backs and 2C2 for halfs. Case 2: 6C5 for backs and 2C1 for halfs. Case 3: 6C5 for backs and 2C2 for halfs. Total: 8C6(6C4*2C2+6C5*2C1+6C5*2C2)

Answer (score 0):

Let's treat the player that can play back or half as the "flex player".

Now we have three cases to sum together:

**1** The flex player is in the back position

**2** The flex player is in the half position

**3** The flex player is not selected

See if you can figure out how to find the number of teams for each case, then simply add them together for the total number of teams possible.